# Is Magmi Safe To use in magento for Import export on advance level

Tags: import, magmi, importexport

I want to import export category.....attributes...and some complex data....
I heard about magmi tools for the faster import export...its uses Direct Sql Query...Is it safe...is it create any error in magento database....magento databse is very complex....so its hard to find error ...so I want to know that is magmi is safe for magento import export.......
It is also very hard to understand ...So i want to know that is it good with magento....

Comment: magmi is safe,as long as you know how to use it. as any import can trash your database.

Comment: I would recommend not installing this on a live server only on a local dev environment as there have been a lot of exploits with magmi on live servers see: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35052/ and https://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&description=magmi&e_author=

Comment: @rob3000 can you explain your answer....

Comment: so basically you'd need to setup a local development environment that's not public facing and then do the import or necessary tasks. I wouldn't recommend installing this on a live server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use magmi if you want, it's *mostly* safe. Take care to set it up properly so it isn't accessible from the outside. I'd suggest trying AvS_FastSimpleImport (my module) or ApiImport (by Daniel Sloof) as an alternative - it uses Magento core functionality for import and no direct database access.

You can find a comparison of the different import methods at https://www.integer-net.com/product-import-with-magento/.